# How can I disable the intellisense for knockout in Web Developer Tools 2012.2 RTW

Tags: visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, intellisense

My Visual Studio works extremely slow when it comes to newly added intellisense support for Knockout that was shipped with Web Developer Tools 2012.2 RTW. Somehow my studio got updated to the latest version of it and now I cannot work! How can I disable this thing please?

Comment: Can you try running "devenv.exe /SafeMode from visual studio developer command prompt and let us know whether you see the same perf hit? This will help identifying issue you are seeing. Also let us know all 3rd party extensions you are using in the project.

Comment: Why there is no option to disable this feature from the options dialog? This is so annoying when something that worked ok stops working and there is no way to get back to the way it worked before. Who do you think you guys are to decide foe everybody what features to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/04/disabling-knockout-intellisense.aspx) has details on how to disable KO intellisense.

Add a new *String Value* to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\HTML Editor` with the name `KnockoutSupportEnabled` and the value `0`.

If you're using the Express version, add it to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VWDExpress\11.0\HTML Editor`.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  I turned it off because it was putting gray highlighting all over the place, incorrectly.  Seems like the KO intellisense is still in beta.

Comment: I can't figure this out for VS2015. Best I can do is fix the horrendous input lag when typing inside a data-bind attribute: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript -> General -> Uncheck "Auto list members"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what worked for me:

1. Go Uninstall programs and uninstall "Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2012.2". You won't be able to open web projects anymore after doing it. Don't freak out.
2. Start the installer of Visual Studio 2012 and go "Modify"
3. Pick the "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" feature and install it.
4. Problem solved you have returned to the previous version of the Web Developer Tools without the buggy knockout.js intellisense.

Comment: I have the problem of VS crashes with the final release of 2012.02. Guess I have to just uninstall it completely

Comment: Please read this blog which lists down steps to turn off the KO intellisense: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/04/disabling-knockout-intellisense.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Try this reg setting for disabling KO.[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\HTML Editor] "KnockoutSupportEnabled"="0"

Comment: Now check the  blog link from my earlier comment and it will work.